# I'd like to reuse an ephemeral port after closing it

Tags: udp

I want to open an ephemeral port, use it for a bit, close it --- but not allow any other processes to grab it --- and then open it again.  This sequence of events allows me to test one network endpoint going down, and coming back up.  In real life the port number would not be ephemeral.

I want to do this to test my network connectivity code.  I'm running a large number of tests in parallel, and they use ephemeral ports to avoid conflicting with each other (and I'd rather not have a central directory of ports).  My test is occasionally failing because it is unable to reacquire the same port, presumably because another test has grabbed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember what it was and explicitly bind to it the second time. But you can't prevent anyone else grabbing it in between. Be quick ;-)

Comment: In my case it turns out that every now and then another test is quicker :-(